# Correct way to pass an object through to a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In this example, using express, I want to pass through the 'res' so I can direct the page when the functions are complete:

```
function dostuff(id) {
  console.log(id);
};

app.post('/:id', function(req, res){
  dostuff(req.params.id, function() {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

But 'res' isn't known. So I have tried to pass it into the function arguments with:

```
dostuff(req.params.id, function(res) {
```

but that doesn't work. How should one do this correctly?

**EDIT**

So I appear to have lost the context in simplifying the code to an example. This is my original code - note the 'res' being passed through, but the error generated is that res.redirect is not a function:

```
app.delete('/todo/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = [req.params.id];
  couch.view('items', 'all_items', {keys: id}, function(err, body, res) {
    if (!err) {
      var row = body.rows[0];
      var id = row.id;
      var rev = row.value.rev;
      couch.destroy(id, rev);
      res.redirect('/todo');
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work if `dostuff` doesn't do anything with its second parameter? Your inline function being passed to it is being ignored. If you do call your callback argument, your example does work.

Comment: Ok, that's maybe because I've tried to do a simplified version and have lost the context. I will edit with my actual code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your callback as `function(err, body, res)`, you are expecting the `couch.view` to pass res as the last argument, but it's not passing it.

In your case, you should just remove `res` from the argument list so that you are not shadowing `res` that had been available from the closure.

```
app.delete('/todo/:id', function(req, res){
  var id = [req.params.id];
  couch.view('items', 'all_items', {keys: id}, function(err, body) {
    // Don't define a res argument to this callback, use it from the closure
    ...
    res.redirect('/todo');
  });
});
```

## Answer to the original question

Your `doStuff` needs to take a callback, in your case, you don't need to pass it through because it's available through the closure.

```
function dostuff(id, cb) {
  console.log(id);
  // Faking doing something async
  setTimeout(cb, 1000);
};

app.post('/:id', function(req, res){
  dostuff(req.params.id, function() {
    // res is available from the closure
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Here's another solution in case your callback is not defined inline.

```
function dostuff(id, cb) {
  console.log(id);
  // Faking doing something async
  setTimeout(function, 1000);
};

function afterFinished(res) {
   res.redirect('/');
}
app.post('/:id', function(req, res){
  dostuff(req.params.id, afterFinished.bind(null, res));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for updating! This gets rid of the error, but the deleted item is not being removed from the live view, presumably as the 'destroy' command hasn't completed before the redirect occurs. I realise this isn't the neatest way of updating the content, but this is really just for my understanding. I've tried to put the redirect as a callback too, such as: couch.destroy(id, rev, function() {
        res.redirect('/todo');

Comment: I've tried this also (with a matching 'redir' function obvs): couch.destroy(id, rev, redir.bind(null, res));

Comment: @user4893295 Your other suggestion should work (as much as mine). Regarding your problem, if the callback has been called before it's supposed to, that's a separate question that should have a new post so it can be useful to others who may have the same problem. This call is about passing parameters to callbacks and a post should not keep evolving as you find new issues (but your original question has been answered)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the res to the callback like below:

```
dostuff(req.params.id, (function(res) {
    res.redirect('/');
}).bind(this, res));
```

Comment: This is not a very good suggestion because `res` is already available through the closure. It would be OK with full context as I have provided in my answer (if the callback is not inline)